# How are the methods of a module accessed without class instantiation in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/international')

print(r.status_code)
print(r.headers)
```

As far as I can understand, in this code I am assigning the result of the `requests.get('https://www.theguardian.com/international')` call to `r` which is the response to the HTTP request. But how can I use the `.status_code` and `.header` methods with `r`? `r` is not an instance of a class as far as I can tell.

Comment: what if `get` returns an instance of a class? Did you think to check in the docs? Did you try to use the specified methods and failed? What is the actual question here?

Comment: `get` is a function. Inside that function instance of `request.Response` will be generated and populated with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Python Requests quickstart guide](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/user/quickstart/#make-a-request)   `requests.get(url)` simply returns a `Response` object, thus in your example, `r` is assigned to that object, which enables you to access its attributes such as `status_code`, `text`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`r` is actually an instance of class:[`request.Response`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). You can read documentation of [`requests.get`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.get) for more information.